# How do I load collada object to three.js?

Tags: three.js, collada

I'm new to three.js and am having trouble loading a collada object to it. I can't get home.dae to render in the browser.

I updated the code under SECOND UPDATE based on the answers.

```
        // INITIAL

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load('home.dae', function(collada){
            scene.add(collada);
        });

        function render() {
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        render();


        // SECOND UPDATE

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.set(0,1,4);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

        loader.load('home.dae', function(collada){
            scene.add(collada.scene);
        });

        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your render function is called only once. Try with this -

```
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Also check if you file path is valid.

Comment: I tried it and it's still not rendering. The dae file is in the same directory as the html file.

Answer (score 1):

Few things that come to mind:

- as @Rasheduzzaman already noted, the render-function is called too early (when you call `render()`, the `scene.add(collada);` call can not have happened. Use his Answer instead.
- the collada-loader works a bit differently: the documentation isn't clear about this, but the returned object is a collection of all the stuff that could've been in the collada-file, see here for a list: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js#L181-L204 (also: use the debugger from the browser-devtools to inspect the data you find there). You will probably want to do `scene.add(collada.scene)` or similar.
- you are not setting a position for the camera, so it is located at (0,0,0), which might not be a great idea, try `camera.position.set(0,1,4)` or something like that.
- you need to know what to expect: what is the size of the model you are loading? Where is it placed? Make sure to point your camera there (could use `camera.lookAt(object.position)`) and adjust nearPlane and farPlane accordingly.

Comment: I can see the images and dae file in the Network tab under the browser's developer's tool, but the object itself is not rendering in the browser.

Comment: ok, so you have the camera looking from (0,1,4) to (0,0,0), but maybe the object is just way bigger than that, or somewhere else. Try to add the `THREE.OrbitControls()` to your scene and navigate a bit around. (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js), you could also try to make that collada-object accessible from the console or inspect it in the debugger (look for `geometry.boundingBox` and other properties).

Comment: also your second update is missing the `render`-call, is this just left out?